# How to publish android app / open it on my mobile

Tags: c#, android, monogame

I have written a game using C# monogame android. I want to first transfer it to my personal phone and then upload it to google play possibly? How could i do that ? I saw that it is 25$ is this all the fee there is to it ? Can someone reference a blog to me, or guide me through, that would be helpful. All the information i found on google was kind of confusing.

Comment: https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shiro If you have [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package) file (Android Package executable file) then you can directly copy it on your phone and install it.

Comment: Yes, google play charged $25 one time with lifetime validity.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project `"YourProject"\bin\Debug` and copy yourprojct.apk file to your phone and install it.

For google play watch [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Publishing-an-Android-App-to-the-Google-Play-Store/) tutorial.

Comment: Yes, google play charged $25 one time with lifetime validity.

Answer (score 0):

Which IDE are you using to develop. Intellij, Android Studio and Eclipse. Connect your phone to the system, enable the debugging in settings. 
Click on the Run button, it loads the app to your phone.
You can also use the emulator (using AVD manager) in all the IDE mentioned above. Genymotion(an external emulator) can also be used

Comment: im using xamarin studio

Comment: I guess this link should help you. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/